How to get scikit-learn to ensure that all prediction outputs should sum to 100%?
I have a 'MultiOutputRegressor' which is based on a 'LinearRegression' regressor.
I am using it to predict three outputs per row of X_data (like a classifier) which represent the percentage likelihood of three outcomes.
The regressor is fitted against y_data where the three labels sum correctly to 100%.
Obviously the regressor doesn't really know that it's three prediction outputs should sum, it just knows roughly what values they should be.
Is there a way that I can tell the regressor explicitly that one of the rules is that all three prediction outputs should together sum to 100%?

Shortly, no. Regressors cannot know this. Your problem is a multi-class classification problem. You need to use classifier for your problem. Classifier model predicts probabilites of three labels. And sum of them will be 1 (100%).
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html

Thank you :)
Is there a way I can get Classifiers to work with floats, or must I round all the y_data figures into integers before fitting?

You're welcome :) if you have only three different target valuei you can map them to 0, 1, and 2 or something like that. inputs are ok as floats.

Nice latinisation of the plural of value :)
Had a thought.. if my floats are two decimal places can I just multiply them by 100 and use them as integers in the 100's order of magnitude? Will the classifier accept that?

Further.. while I have you... Is it correct to call both classifiers and regressors 'estimators'? And are there any that are something other than classifiers and regressors?

if you want to predict classes, it doesn't matter target are multiplied or converted to string. if you have a target column to be predicted, it is supervised learning. your problem is regression or classification. you should make a decision about your problem. and both of them isn't possible at the same time. you should read about supervised learning methods.
